Sum value if matching value is not blank in range leaving it blank if empty
So I am trying to get my sheet to not have a bunch of 0s.
Currently I am using =SUMIF('Tracking Sheet'!A:A, A5, 'Tracking Sheet'!M:M)
The sheet is for daily tracking 'Tracking Sheet'!A:A date format and 'Tracking Sheet'!M:M is the numeric value to be SUMed.


You may try:
=let(x,<your SUMIF formula>,if(x=0,,x))


dang you are fast...I have never used that formula before.
